# Is that any new tool used to develop android app by using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know for the confirmation to develop the tool in vb.net for developing the android app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a possibility to develop android apps in visual studio.

You just need Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or More.
You need either Xamarin or Apache Cordova to develop apps for android.

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Cordova CTP 3.1 in Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4 to develop an android messaging app like whatsapp.

In the client side, i.e. the index.html running on the andriod phone or iphone, I use the javascript, css, and jquery.

In the server side, I create Web Services with CORS in VB.net.

For example, 2 users A & B, when A send a message to B, I do the following:

1. A phone's index.html, input message, and using async ajax with CORS, call www.myweb.com/sendmessage.asmx(written by VB.net) .   Then inside sendmessage.asmx, store message in SQL server.
2. A phone's index.html, after getting response from sendmessage.asmx, call www.myweb.com/signalr (written by C#.net, this part cannot be written by vb.net).  And this signalr call B phone's index.html receiveMessage function.
3. B phone's index.html, in receiveMessage function, call www.myweb.com/receivemessage.asmx(written by VB.net), to read the message from the SQL server.

The above techniques uses lots of javascript and vb.net codings and use minimal c# codings.  c# only used to acknowledge message, with minimal coding logic.  (Because I am a vb programmer!)